# Use Postgresql function in SELECT and WHERE

Tags: function, postgresql, select

Supposing there is query, which calculates distance between given point and points stored in database. The purpose is to find few closest points to a given one

```
select x,y, get_distance(25,13,x,y) as dis
from points
order by dis
```

But as a condition, i'd like to set restriction for distance in order to get only results with distance <1000

```
select x,y, get_distance(25,13,x,y) as dis
from points
where dis <1000
order by dis
```

result of this query is :
ERROR:  column "dis" does not exist

So i'm forced to write function call twice:

```
  select x,y, get_distance(25,13,x,y) as dis
    from points
    where get_distance(25,13,x,y) <1000
    order by dis
```

Althought, function get_distance is declared as **immutable** and does not compute twice as declared in docs, the query itself looks ugly.

Is there any way to use result of **get_distance as dis** in condition and not to write it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT x, y, get_distance(25, 13, x, y) dis FROM points
) t
WHERE dis < 1000
ORDER BY dis
```

Comment: It is possible that this version will have to create a full temp table, with all the distances first, and then discard and order the points. The other version, although uglier to read, would discard points as soon as they did not match, and then create the temp table for ordering. So, depending on how many points there are and how many match the condition, this version could be very slow.

Comment: @AlexSiri, you have only a guess. And I suspect it's wrong. The SQL describes the data I want to get. The database engine is welcome to filter, sort, etc. in whatever order it wants. There is no imperative programming here. This *may* do what you suggest. But without evidence, I'd lean towards the assumption that PostgreSQL is smart.

Comment: you might be right, as I created this fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0a9f/3) and found that both options have the same execution plan (at least with very little data)

Comment: As a remark, just tested both queries with explain (analyze ,buffers)  and the was no difference in query plan at all.